# Why is adding jquery scripts for hidden divs causing the navbar to stop working on mobile devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new at this coding and website development thing and just started crash coursing in HTML and CSS a few weeks ago for work. I've built a multi-page website using adaptations from the bootstrap "creative" theme and a few other themes. I have a bootstrap navbar that functions on all the pages. On one of the pages, I was asked to change it to have hidden divs that are revealed when you click on it. I didn't know how to do this, but did some researching on JQuery and got it to work. Unfortunately, when I added the two new JQuery scripts for this to work, the navbar dropdown function on mobile stopped working. I have since removed the two scripts and am using the Bootstrap Accordion function, but the navbar dropdown menu still isn't working. I have not changed the scripts from what it was before. The beginning of my code works on all my pages and looks something like this:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content"ie=edge&quot;">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <title>Title</title>
        <link href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="/css/carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="/css/creative.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
            <link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {$('dropdown-toggle').dropdown()});</script>
</head>
<header> 
<nav>...</nav>
<div>...</div>
</header>
<section style="padding: 10%; padding-top: 5%;">
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="GeneralQuestions">
    <h2 class="FAQ2">General Questions</h2>
      <h2 class="panel-title">
        <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#Q1" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Q1">
     Question 1
        </a>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="Q1" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="GeneralQuestions">
      <div class="panel-body">
    Answer
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
      <h2 class="panel-title">
        <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#Q2" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="Q2">
       Question
        </a>
      </h2>
    </div>
    <div id="Q2" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="GeneralQuestions">
      <div class="panel-body">
Answer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Even after removing the two new scripts the error stops popping up, but the navbar dropdown menu still doesn't work in mobile view on this page. It works on all the other pages still, and even on a previous version of the same page before I added the hidden divs, but it won't work now. Can anyone explain why having hidden divs later in the page is causing the navbar dropdown menu to stop working and perhaps how to solve this problem?
Any help will be much appreciated!
Thanks!

Comment: Two notes: FIrst, you're using two different versions of jQuery (both of which are not very up-to-date). Second, what version of Bootstrap are you using?

Comment: I would address the two instances of jQuery and see if your error still occurs.  For Bootstrap v3 you should be fine using jQuery 1.4.4 (the Docs for Bootstrap do show 1.12.4 though.)

Comment: I updated the JQuery and still had issues, so I've updated the question with all the new bug fixes I've attempted, but it still isn't working.

Comment: Resolved. I have no idea what fixed it, but all of the sudden it started working again.